# Android: Casting serializable out of bundle fails in phone but not emulator

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, bundle, serializable

long time listener, first time caller, so apologies if my formatting is terrible.

TL/DR Version:

Put serializable class[] into bundle/intent within my service.  Send to main activity via BroadcastReceiver.  When pulling object[] out of bundle and trying to cast back to my custom class, dump occurs on my phone(MOTO Razr HD), but not within my Android Studio emulator.

I have only gotten into Android within the past few months, and have relied heavily on their tutorials/google to learn, so there is a good chance this may be a gap.

Ok, so my purpose here is to have a Service running during my various activities, and to have said service be in charge of server communication (creating a Chess game essentially for android experience).  Emulator was working as intended during my testing,but when i run on my phone, it dumps.

I have had other serializable objects being passed between activities within bundles, and that previously has worked fine. With the introduction of this service however, it seems to be losing sight of the actual type of Object it is (shown via screenshots below), and fails to allow me to cast back from an Object[] to my GameContainer[].

My next step is to try a different phone as well....usage of SharedPreferences was not working on my phone at all (the logic for that happens well before the dump occurs), and only started working when i started debugging my phone, despite zero changes in my source code in that time.  My phone may just be borked.

Here is the debugging view of my bundle(s) at various times:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgEmt.jpg

image #1 Here is the debugging view of my bundle after i have put my GameContainer[] in it via bundle.putSerializable(String, Obj[]) on my Phone

image #2 Here is the debugging view of my bundle after broadcast receiver gets it in my main activity and before it attempts to cast(which causes the dump) on my phone

imgae #3 ANd here is the same as above, only on my emulator on my comp.

I am not sure if the mMap subsets throwing the ClassNotFoundException is helpful...i see that both in my phone and emulator, which makes me assume thats simply because im placing a custom class inside the bundle.

Some code for you guys

my Service - specifically the portion under my Runnalbe if state = RequestedGames.

```
package chess2.Services;


import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.Date;


import ServerStuff.ChessClass;
import chess2.source.GameBoard;
import chess2.source.GameContainer;

public class ChessService extends Service {

protected ChessClass theGame;
protected String myState = "INITIAL";
protected String returnState = "INITIAL";
protected String returnMessage = "";
protected GameBoard myGB = null;
protected GameContainer[] myGC = null;
protected int myGameIndex = -1;
private static final String RM = "RETURNMESSSAGE";
private static final String RS = "RETURNSTATE";
private static final String RO = "RETURNOBJECT";
private static final String RA = "RETURNOBJECTARRAY";

public static final String SERVER_RESPONSE = "com.botna.chess2.server_response";
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
Intent intent;
private Runnable sendUpdatesToActivity = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        intent.putExtra(RS, returnState);
        intent.putExtra(RM, returnMessage);


        if (returnState.equals("REQUESTEDGAMES")) {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putSerializable(RA,myGC);
            intent.putExtras(b);
        }
        if (returnState.equals("GAMELOADED"))
        {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putSerializable(RO,myGB);
            intent.putExtras(b);
        }


        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

};



@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //TODO do something useful

    //make sure our connection is still setup.
    try {
        if (theGame == null) {

            theGame = new ChessClass();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //TODO
    }


    //Gather information out fo the intent and decipher what
    //we need to send to the server based on MODE, STATE, PAYLOAD etc

    //SEnd it to the server, get our response

    //PUt the response in our intent.


    //post our updates, which will trigger stuff in the activity.

    String state = intent.getStringExtra("STATE");
    String result = null;
    String[] payload;

    switch(state) {
        case "INITIAL":
            //this specifies the app just resumed activity or did something else that
            //caused the onDestory method to get executed.

            //we want to try and log in our connection if we have a stored username and pword,
            //otherwise, well send a response that the app needs to gather that.

            //find out if username and password is stored already.
            returnState = "NOSAVEDLOGIN";
            break;

        case "LOGINATTEMPT":
            payload = intent.getStringArrayExtra("PAYLOAD");
            if(myState.equals("INITIAL")) {
                try {
                    result = theGame.login(payload[0], payload[1]);

                    //login was a success.
                    returnState = "AUTHENTICATED";
                    returnMessage = result;
                    myState = "LOGGEDIN";
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    //Wrong username/pwrod/ or generic error.
                    returnState = "ERROR";
                    returnMessage = e.getMessage();
                }
            }
            else
                returnState = "ALREADYLOGGED";
            break;

        case "REGISTERATTEMPT":
            payload = intent.getStringArrayExtra("PAYLOAD");
            try {
                result = theGame.register(payload[0], payload[1]);
                //login was a success.
                returnState = "JUSTTOAST";
                returnMessage = result;
            } catch (Exception e) {

                //invalid username, username already exists, something else.
                returnState = "ERROR";
                returnMessage = e.getMessage();
            }

            break;

        case "CREATEGAME":
            payload = intent.getStringArrayExtra("PAYLOAD");

            try{

                result = theGame.createNewGame(payload[0],payload[1]);
                returnState = "JUSTTOAST";
                returnMessage = result;

            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                //invalid username, username already exists, something else.
                returnState = "ERROR";
                returnMessage = e.getMessage();
            }
            break;
        case "REQUESTGAMES":
            payload = intent.getStringArrayExtra("PAYLOAD");

            try{

                theGame.refreshGames();
                GameContainer[] myGames = theGame.getCurrentGames();
                myState = returnState = "REQUESTEDGAMES";
                returnMessage = "";
                myGC = myGames;

            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                //invalid username, username already exists, something else.
                returnState = "ERROR";
                returnMessage = e.getMessage();
            }

            break;

        case "CHOOSEBLACK":
            char variant = intent.getCharExtra("PAYLOAD", 'z');

            if(variant != 'z')
            {


                try {
                    theGame.updateClassChoice(variant);
                    //success, start a game jsut the same
                    returnState = "GAMELOADED";
                    returnMessage = theGame.getName();
                    myGB = theGame.getGame();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {

                    //invalid username, username already exists, something else.
                    returnState = "ERROR";
                    returnMessage = e.getMessage();
                }
            }

        case "LOADGAME":
            int index = intent.getIntExtra("INDEX", -1);
            myGameIndex = index;
            try{

                result =  theGame.loadGame(index);
                if(result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                    returnState = "GAMELOADED";
                    returnMessage = theGame.getName();
                    myGB = theGame.getGame();
                }
                else
                {
                    //black needs update
                    returnState = "BLACKUPDATE";
                    returnMessage = "";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                //invalid username, username already exists, something else.
                returnState = "ERROR";
                returnMessage = e.getMessage();
            }

            break;

        case "ATTEMPTMOVE":
            int[] moves = intent.getIntArrayExtra("PAYLOAD");

            try{

                result = theGame.sendMove(moves);
                returnState = "MOVEMADE";
                returnMessage = result;

            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                //invalid username, username already exists, something else.
                returnState = "ERROR";
                returnMessage = e.getMessage();
            }

            break;

        case "REFRESHGAME":

            try{

                result =  theGame.loadGame(myGameIndex);
                if(result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                    returnState = "GAMELOADED";
                    returnMessage = theGame.getName();
                    myGB = theGame.getGame();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                //invalid username, username already exists, something else.
                returnState = "ERROR";
                returnMessage = e.getMessage();
            }

            break;

        case "ENACTSKIRMISH":

            int wager = intent.getIntExtra("PAYLOAD",-1);

            try{

                result = theGame.sendSkirmish(wager);
                returnState = "SKIRMISHSENT";
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                //invalid username, username already exists, something else.
                returnState = "ERROR";
                returnMessage = e.getMessage();
            }

            break;

        case "FINISHSKIRMISH":
            int finish = intent.getIntExtra("PAYLOAD",-1);


            try{

                result = theGame.finishSkirmish(finish);
                returnState = "SKIRMISHSENT";
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                //invalid username, username already exists, something else.
                returnState = "ERROR";
                returnMessage = e.getMessage();
            }

            break;
    }
    //state suggests what we are being sent from the activity.
    //do the needful based on its payload and other stuff,
    //send to server, and send back the servers response so our
    //activity can do wahtever is necessary from taht point forward.

    handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToActivity);
    handler.post(sendUpdatesToActivity);
    return Service.START_STICKY;

}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    intent = new Intent(SERVER_RESPONSE);


}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    theGame.disconnect();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Here is my broadcast Receiver in my Main activity, since im running out of space.  Specifically, look for case "REQUESTEDGAMES" to see the bundle line, which i have marked with a -> to point it out.

```
package com.botna.chess2;




import java.util.ArrayList;

import chess2.Services.ChessService;

import chess2.source.GameContainer;
import chess2.Activities.*;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import ServerStuff.ChessClass;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static final String PREFERENCES = "com.botna.chess2";
    public static final String INITIAL = "INITIAL";
    public static final String LOGGED = "LOGGED";
    private static final String RM = "RETURNMESSSAGE";
    private static final String RS = "RETURNSTATE";
    private static final String RO = "RETURNOBJECT";
    private static final String RA = "RETURNOBJECTARRAY";


    protected ChessClass theGame;
    protected Toast toast = null;
    protected String[] variants={"Classic", "Reapers", "Nemesis","Empowered",
            "Animals","Two-Kings"};
    protected String[] myGamesString;
    protected GameContainer[] myGames;
    protected String myName;
    protected String state = null;
    protected boolean transitioning = false;
    protected MainActivity pointer = this;
    private Intent myService;


    private BroadcastReceiver broadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateActivity(intent);
        }
    };


    private void updateActivity(Intent intent)
    {


        String returnState = intent.getStringExtra(RS);
        String returnMessage = intent.getStringExtra(RM);
        Bundle b = null;

        switch(returnState)
        {
            case "NOSAVEDLOGIN":

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                break;

            case "AUTHENTICATED":
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
                state = LOGGED;

                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
                String restoredUName = prefs.getString("USERNAME", null);
                String restoredPWord = prefs.getString("PASSWORD", null);
                if(restoredUName == null || restoredPWord == null);
                {
                //need to save our username and password in the preferences now.
                //no previous shared preferences, lets update it.

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("USERNAME", myService.getStringArrayExtra("PAYLOAD")[0]);
                editor.putString("PASSWORD",myService.getStringArrayExtra("PAYLOAD")[1]);
                editor.commit();
                }

                break;

            case "REQUESTEDGAMES":

                b = intent.getExtras();
                 //DUMPS RIGHT HERE AT THE ->  
                ->myGames = (GameContainer[])b.getSerializable(RA);
                //myGames = (GameContainer[])intent.getSerializableExtra(RA);

                int counter = 1;


                if(myGames.length == 0 || myGames[0] == null)
                {
                    toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You dont have any games =(",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String temp;
                    for(int i = 0; i< myGames.length; i++)
                    {
                        if(myGames[i] != null)
                        {
                            temp = myGames[i].getWhiteTeam() + " vs " + myGames[i].getBlackTeam() ;
                            if(myGames[i].getWinner() != null)
                            {
                                //game is over.
                                temp = temp + " - Game Over";
                            }
                            else if(myGames[i].getBlackVar() < 'A')
                            {
                                temp = temp + " - Awaiting Pick";
                            }
                            else if(myGames[i].getTurn().equals(myName))
                                temp = temp + " - Your Turn";
                            else
                                temp = temp + " - Their Turn";
                            list.add(temp);
                            counter++;
                        }
                    }
                    myGamesString = null;
                    myGamesString = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
                    GameChoiceDialog gameDialog = new GameChoiceDialog();
                    state = "GAMESELECTED";
                    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    gameDialog.show(fm, "Dialog Fragment");
                }
                break;

            case "BLACKUPDATE":
                        ClassChoiceDialog classChoiceDialog = new ClassChoiceDialog();

                        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        classChoiceDialog.show(fm, "Dialog Fragment");
                break;
            case "GAMELOADED":

                        state = "PLAYINGGAME";
                        b = intent.getExtras();
                        Intent playGameIntent = new Intent(this, PlayGameActivity.class);
                        playGameIntent.putExtras(b);
                        startActivityForResult(playGameIntent, 0);
                break;
            case "JUSTTOAST":
            case "ERROR":
                if(toast != null)
                    toast.cancel();

                toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),returnMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                break;


        }
    }
```

and Here is part of my game container showing it is Serializable

```
package chess2.source;



import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.UUID;



public class GameContainer implements Serializable{
```

Depending on the interest this generates, my next step will be to move away from Broadcast receivers and to simply bind to the Service, as per my understanding with the exact 1 tutorial i read about binding to services, it allows you to execute methods directly within the service class, which should bypass the necessity of transporting my GameContainer[] via bundle and broadcast receiver, and simply let it be a return parameter.

Any help would be great! Got pretty close to the character limit, i have a lot more code to show if it could be of any use!

Comment: Slightly embarassing that i cound't find articles on this previously, but apparently java has a really hard time casting an Object[] to CustomClass[].  Many articles im seeing show that if it is coming from an Object[], it has to be iterated through and caste individually.  Ill have to give that a shot and see if that makes any difference.

When i think about it, the casting i was using previously for this Array was straight out of InputStream from my server, so maybe it never hits that intermediary 'object' state, which is why it is failing now and not before.  Still not sure on SIm vs phone.

Answer (score 0):

Java apparently does not like casting from an Object[] to a CustomClass[].  However, doing bundle.getSerializable() and placing it into an Object[], and then casting each object individually fixed the problem.  There must be some discrepancy between my phone and my emulator!